# HTML Entities in Rails link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-entities, link-to

How do I insert HTML entities in a rails link_to?

For instance &#10029 will give you a star character, how do I insert this inside a quote?

For example,

```
<%= link_to " &#10029 Home", root_path %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to raw("&#10029 Home"), root_path %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this method for escape:

```
<%= link_to raw("&#10029 Home"), root_path %>
```

Don’t use html_safe() unless you’re sure your string isn’t nil. Instead use the raw() method, which wont raise an exception on nil.

[Api Rails raw()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw)